# Add a tag to NSArray object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I want to create 2 arrays, and populate my table view with that arrays. Then, if user click on a cell, that contain object from first array, i want to perform transition to my detail controller "one". Therefore, if user tap on cell, that contain text from second array, i want to perform segue for detail controller "two".

How to achieve that? I can't put tag on array objects and check it.

Edit: or, if NSDictionary suitable for that case, i could use them instead.

Comment: you must have mixed the data in single array to display in the list, correct?

Comment: @JitendraSingh yes, there is single table that contain data from 2 arrays

Comment: Why is your data in two separate arrays? It should be in one array.

Comment: @rmaddy it come from different sources and i need to distinguish it.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban As the others have asked, how are you combining your sources in order to display them in your table? For example what's in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @rmaddy if i populate data from 2 NSArrays, how could i determine, when user tap on cell, where he tap on cell that contain text from array 1 or from array 2?

Comment: You figure it out the same way you know how to access the data from the two arrays in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But as everyone is hinting, you really should only have one array. It will make things much easier. It will be make your data source code easier and it will help support sorting and searching a lot easier too.

Comment: Could you please share how you are picking item from array in cellForRowAtIndexPath method? I need to know if you have created third array by combining the data from two arrays or you randomly choose an array from the two and picks an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be create a third array with NSDictionary objects with two keys 'tag' and 'data'. 'tag' key will hold the information about which array and 'data' key will hold data from the array.

```
NSMutableArray *tableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
for (id obj in array1) {
    [tableArray addObject:@{@"tag":@1, @"data":obj}];
}
for (id obj in array2) {
    [tableArray addObject:@{@"tag":@2, @"data":obj}];
}
```

Then use this new array to populate your table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
....

id obj = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"data"];

....
}
```

and on didSelectRowAtIndexpath you can check value for 'tag' key to check whether it is from array1 or array2

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
....
NSNumber *tag = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"tag"];
    if (tag.intValue == 1) {
        //controller 1
    }
    else if (tag.intValue == 2) {
        //controller 2
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of having an array of data elements, you could have an array of MyDataClass, which has attributes for your data, and to identify the source.

You can use a single array to populate the table, and as suggested have different methods for populating the table cell based on the source.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of looking to this problem. Firstly, you have to understand that you can populate a table view with only a single array; however this array can be made from multiple arrays.

Without getting ourselves dirty into multiple data structures that might provide a lot of redundancy than efficiency, a simple way would be to check for the array number in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Example:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    <Type> obj = tableViewArray[indexPath.row];
    if (obj in array1)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The tableViewArray is probably `array1+array2`.

Comment: Is there really exist statement if (object in array){...}? I never seen "in"

Comment: That's just the algorithm. You can use `containsObject` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/containsObject:).